# While popping off view controller Navigation Bar Title glitch in animation and sometimes shifts to left?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

When I push a view controller and try to pop it via Screen Edge Gesture or simply from back button sometimes the navigation title shutters and its gets stuck to the left alignment means just beside to my LeftBarButtonItem.
This makes the app looks slow?
Any idea why this is happening?

[image]

Comment: can u show us the issue ?

Comment: Please post the relevant code for the pushing and popping of the view controller.

Comment: @Snusmumrikken its simply pushviewcontroller call and on taping on back button its popviewcontroller.

Comment: @Mr.T screenshot is added.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23710320/3480716